# WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8081/.../.../...' failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available

Tags: java, angular, websocket

I have to use Websocket connection in my project with angular 2
I have trouble with creating Websocket connection with error 
'WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8081/.../.../..' failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available'
Here's my code

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws:localhost:8081/../../..');
```

I have been stack for a few days. Please anyone who know about this help me.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can the websocket wrapper from the rxjs library.

Import it like this:

```
import {webSocket, WebSocketSubject} from 'rxjs/webSocket';
```

And then create one like this:

```
private webSocket: WebSocketSubject = webSocket(environment.chatUrl);
```

Then you can subscribe to it to get inbound messages:

```
this.subscription = this.webSocket.subscribe(
  msg => {
   // do something with the message
  },
  err => {
   // handle the error
   console.log('error!', err);
  },
  () => {
    // handle getting disconnected
    console.log('websocket closed');
  }
);
```

And send out a message:

```
this.webSocket.next(message);
```

And don't forget to unsubscribe from the websocket when you're finished.

Comment: Thanks. But finally realized that error is occur cuz of Websocket Server with java
If I add spring-security.jar and that error occur.

Answer (score 0):

this is happened due to following reason
your http url and websocket url is not matched at authentication time

your http url is

> http://localhost:port/something..

and your websocket url is
`var webs = new WebSocket("ws://192.168...:port/something..");`

or vice versa

to fix this issue keep both url same